# Reject record but get reason (Workflow)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm stuck at a customization in question.

I have a basic approval workflow.
However, when rejecting records (say Journal Entry),
I want to show a comment box before the rejection process continues.
The message entered by the user in the comment box will then be populated to a custom field I have on the record form.

I'm not sure if this is possible. It's kinda similar to how you get the chance to input Delete reason when deleting records.

Thanks a ton!

-Jet

Comment: I thought of using native prompt boxes or 2.0's dialog module. However these only work on client side scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I did it.

1. Create a simple suitelet that will let the user enter the reason and update the record.
2. Create a custom workflow action script to call the suitelet.
3. Put the custom workflow action script in a separate workflow state.  Have the workflow transition to this state when clicking on the reject button.

Comment: Hey @Rusty Shackles, thanks for your thoughts.
In this method, the page goes to a different page (suitelet form) am I right?

So say in the Suitelet, if the user presses cancel or doesn't submit the suitelet form, I must transition back to the state of pending approval right?

Comment: Yes. So what I did was it they click on cancel, I just bring them back to the original record.  I do nothing to it, but when they click Ok or Save I save the reason they entered on a field on the record and set the status of the record to 'Rejected'.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Rusty Shackles!